# Shutdown and Reboot disabled after upgrade to Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: xubuntu, shutdown, xfce, 22.04

I just recently upgraded my Xubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04.

What I noticed: Everywhere in the Xfce GUI the shutdown and reboot options are greyed out:

- When I click on the whiskermenu, there is a turn-off-button which opens a dialog window with "log off", "restart", "shutdown" and "change user" where restart and shutdown are greyed out.
- When I click on the action buttons in the menu bar, there are shutdown and restart options which are, again, greyed out.
- When I log off and return to the login screen, there is a shutdown button which is again, greyed out

I kept my user profile during dist-upgrade and before everything worked as inteded. I use lightdm as my display manager.

However, I am able to shutdown the system via `shutdown -h now` or similar.

How can I reinstate the proper function of the GUI shutdown?